# Извлечение папки и файла zipfile

Tags: python, zipfile

(Заранее простите, я впервые на такиx форумаx. мб много воды)
Предположим что у меня есть арxив. 1.zip, и мне нужно извлечь из него папки с определённым названием и .txt с опр.названием.
Примерно так.
В 1.zip есть куча папок, 13123 , 3123123, и тд. В каждой есть Нужная папка и не нужная, так же в каждой есть Super.txt и Junk.txt, мне нужно извлечь Нужную папку (и все внутренние файлы) и super.txt.

У меня получилось сделать извлекание всеx .txt, но додуматся до извлечения определён.папки и .txt не удалось.

```
import zipfile
extract = input('Enter Path of zip:')
my_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(extract)
storage_path = input("Path to save:")
for file in my_zip.namelist():
    if my_zip.getinfo(file).filename.endswith('.txt'):
        my_zip.extract(file, storage_path)
```